# jQuery UI Slider Being Selected Below DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I can click any element below (not above) and it'll change according to the mouses X axis. This seems to be the norm for jQuery UI which is odd to say the least.

http://jsfiddle.net/devcurry_com/JSmWM/

```
    $('#musicVolume').slider({
             range: "min",
             min: 0,
             max: 100,

             change: function (event, ui) {
                 alert('Stopped at ' + ui.value);
             }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't self-close `div`s like that in HTML, so the parser simply ignores the `/` in `<div />` leaving the `div` open until it force-closes the `div` before the `</body>` (or either the closest `</div>` or the closest properly closed parent of that `div`).

So everything after the `<div />` gets caught inside of it and become part of the slider widget and activates it on click, including the `p` element where you display the selected value.

Note: You also can't self-close `p` elements - what you can do is occult the closing tag which is optional in HTML. That feature is not very desirable for your use-case though.
Other note: `<p />` is valid markup as `/` is syntactic sugar and `p` elements don't require a closing tag, but it won't generate an empty `p` element as you'd expect if [*phrasing content*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/content-models.html#phrasing-content-0) follows it. Properly close it with a `</p>` if you want an empty `p`.

Properly closing your `div`s and `p`s will fix the issue. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JSmWM/758/)

Comment: Thanks it was the element not being closed